# Find orthogonal matrix $R$ that minimizes $\|R-Q\|_F$ for a complex Matrix Q

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, orthogonal-matrices

I have given a complex matrix $Q \in \mathbb{C}^{3,3}$ and I would like to find the "closest" rotation matrix (meaning $\mathcal{R}$ is orthogonal and $\det{(\mathcal{R})}=1$) $R \in \mathbb{R}^{3,3}$ which minimizes the norm
$$ \|Q-\mathcal{R}\|_F $$
Is there any closed form solution to this problem or an efficient algorithm I could use to compute $R$?

**Background Information**

I am adding some background information to this: In my application, I get a noisy sensor measurement $[B]_{meas}$:

$$ [B]_{meas}=\mathcal{R}[B]_{ref} + \mathcal{N}_B$$

$[B]_{ref}$ is a known, complex 3x3 matrix, $\mathcal{R}$ is an orthogonal, real-valued rotation matrix and $\mathcal{N}_B$ is an additive, complex valued noise matrix (3x3, complex). I am trying to get an estimate for $\mathcal{R}$ given the measurement $[B]_{meas}$.

Right now, the suboptimal method I use is the following:

$$ \operatorname*{argmin}_{\mathcal{R}} || \Re{([B]_{meas}[B]_{ref}^{-1}}) ||_{F}$$

I solve this optimization problem using the Procrustes method. However, I don't think I can use the Procrustes method directly because it will output an unitary matrix and not an orthogonal matrix.

Comment: What do you mean by $\|\cdot\|_2$ in this context? Are you referring to the induced $2$-norm (AKA spectral norm, AKA max singular value norm) or are you referring to the [Frobenius norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm)?

Comment: If you mean the Frobenius norm, then this minimization problem is the complex version of the [orthogonal Procrustes problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_Procrustes_problem). Just as in the real number version, the solution can be obtained from the SVD of $Q$.

Comment: Also, do you really mean to say that you want an "orthogonal" matrix, or are you looking for a unitary matrix? That is: is $R$ allowed to be complex? If so, does it satisfy $R^\top R = I$ or $R^*R = I$, where $R^*$ denotes the conjugate-transpose of $R$?

Comment: My assumption in the second comment was that $R$ was allowed to be complex, and that $R$ must satisfy $R^*R = I$ (i.e. $R$ is the closest **unitary** matrix).

Comment: Thanks for adding that clarification to your comment. A final request: there's been a push to enforce [quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/81360) on the site, and [by those standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/81360) your question is currently incomplete. It would be helpful if you could edit your question to give some context. For example, why are you interested in this problem? Do you have any initial ideas that you tried/considered? Is there any similar problem that you're familiar with that might be relevant?

Comment: Correction: "adding that clarification to your **question**"

Comment: Hello and thanks for your replies. I think the orthogonal Procrustes Problem does indeed correspond to my problem. The matrix should be orthogonal since it corresponds to a rotation matrix in my problem.

Comment: I added some contest to the question to better explain what I am trying to achieve. As I understand it, the Procrustes method will output an unitary matrix since it computes the SVD of a complex matrix. However, I would need an orthogonal matrix, since $\mathcal{R}$ in my context related to a physical rotation.

Comment: In your question you have mentioned that $\mathcal R$ is a *rotation matrix*. If you also want $R$ to be a rotation matrix (so that its determinant is required to be $1$, not $-1$), please state that clearly in your problem formulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is.

> **Claim:** Write $Q = A + iB$ with $A,B \in \Bbb R^{3 \times 3}$ and $i = \sqrt{-1}$. Let $A = U\Sigma V^\top$ be a singular value decomposition of $A$. The matrix $R_* \in O(3)$ given by $R_* = UV^\top$ is such that taking $R = R_*$ minimizes $\|Q - R\|_F$ over $R \in O(3)$.
>
> This minimizer is unique if and only if $A$ is invertible.

*Proof (Minimizer):* Let $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ denote the [Frobenius inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product). Write
\begin{align}
\|Q - W\|_F^2 &= \|Q\|_F^2 + \|W\|_F^2 - 2 \operatorname{Re}[\langle Q,W\rangle]
\\ & = \|Q\|_F^2 + 3 - 2\operatorname{Re}[\langle A - Bi,W\rangle]
\\ & = \|Q\|_F^2 + 3 - 2\operatorname{Re}[\langle A,W\rangle + i \langle B,W\rangle]
\\ & = 3 + \|Q\|_F^2 - 2 \langle A,W \rangle.
\end{align}
Thus, minimizing the objective function is equivalent to maximizing $\langle A,W \rangle$ (over $W \in O(n)$). As [is noted here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_Procrustes_problem#Proof), this maximum is attained with $W = UV^\top$.

*Proof (Uniqueness):* Note that $R$ can be written as $R = UV^\top$ iff $A = R \sqrt{A^\top A}$ is a [polar decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition) of $A$. If $A$ is not invertible, then $A$ has multiple polar decompositions of the form $A = R\sqrt{A^\top A}$, which means that the minimizer is not unique.

Conversely, if $A$ is invertible, then $A$ has the polar decomposition $A = R_* P$ with $P = \sqrt{A^\top A}$, and we can rewrite our second objective function as
$$
\langle A, W \rangle = \operatorname{Tr}([R_* P]^\top W) = 
\operatorname{Tr}(P R_*^\top W) = \langle R_*, W\rangle_P
$$
where we define the bilinear form $\langle X,Y \rangle_P = \operatorname{Tr}(PA^\top B)$. Note that this defines an inner product over $\Bbb R^{3 \times 3}$. Equality holds in the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality if and only if one arguments of the inner product is a positive multiple of the other. Thus, if $\langle R_*, W\rangle_P$ is maximal, then $W$ must be a positive multiple of $R_*$, which (because of the orthogonality constraint) implies that $W = R_*$.

Thus, if $A$ is invertible, then the minimizer is unique.

---

*Note 1:* If $UV^\top$ turns out to have determinant $-1$, then a minimizer among the **rotations** will be
$$
U \pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&-1} V^\top.
$$
This follows from the discussion of [Wahba's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wahba%27s_problem). I am not sure if uniqueness is guaranteed as it was for the problem over the orthogonal matrices.

Notably, if $\|\operatorname{Re}[\mathcal N_B] [B]_{\text{ref}}^{-1}\|_F < \sqrt{2}$, we can guarantee that $UV^\top$ (the overall orthogonal minimizer) will have determinant $1$, which means that this adjustment would not be necessary.

*Note 2:* $R\sqrt{A^\top A}$ is a polar decomposition if and only if $R$ maps $\sqrt{A^\top A}x$ to $Ax$ for all $x$ and maps $\ker(A)$ to $\ker(A^\top)$ isometrically.

Comment: Hello, thanks very much for your answer which answers my question.